# Assign dynamic buttons with name tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make it so that once I put in the rows and columns of my generation for dynamic buttons, it will automatically assign each one with a name. For instance, row 1(A), column 1 will be A1.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
root = Tk()

def redClick(button_num):
    list_of_buttons[button_num].configure(bg="red")

def  buttonsMake():
    ctr = 0  ## button number / offset number in the list
    for columns in range(10):
        for rows in range(3):
            movieSeats=Button(root, text="Empty", bg="green", fg="white", 
width=5, height=1, command=partial(redClick, ctr))
            movieSeats.grid(row=rows,column=columns)
            list_of_buttons.append(movieSeats)
            ctr += 1

list_of_buttons=[]  ## global variable
buttonsMake()
root.mainloop()
```

I expect it to assign each button to a name. I think the global variable can do this, but don't know how.

This is something else(alternative solution) that someone suggested.

```
seats= [["A", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"],
        ["B", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"],
        ["C", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"],
        ["D", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5"],
        ["E", "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5"]]

def make_buttons():
    for r, row in enumerate(seats):
        for c, seat in enumerate(row[1:]):        # N.B. skip first element
            btn = Button(root, text="Empty", bg="#00CC00", height=1,width=6)
            btn.name = seat                       # arbitrary attribute on Button object
            btn.grid(row=r,column=c, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What exactly _is_ 'assigning with a name'? What exactly have you tried? Do you just mean `text`?

Comment: what name? variable name ? use dictionary to keep buttons.

Comment: What is `partial`?

Comment: @Nae - `partial()` is an interesting improvement on the `lambda` concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning names to the buttons as globals will be tricky and is not worth doing. But what you CAN do, which isn't hard at all, is make a dictionary of all the buttons you make, and make the dictionary keys be the "names" you want, like "A1", and the value of each key would be the actual object returned by the Button() call.

I would populate the dictionary within your double-nested `for` loop.

As a side-note, within the double for loop, you could say,

```
import string
:
:
names_d = {}
for ....
    for ....
        buttonName = string.ascii_uppercase[rows] + str(columns + 1) # a working hack
        names_d[buttonName] = Button(...
```

and because I clearly have way too much free time on my hands...

```
def alphanum_name(ai, ni):
    return (ai // 26 + 1) * string.ascii_uppercase[ai % 26] + str(ni + 1)
```

> alphanum_name(1, 2) --> 'B3'
>   alphanum_name(26, 3) --> 'AA4'

Comment: Seems like a good solution. So would new keys be produced based on the amount of rows and columns generated?

Comment: Yup. I added some pseudocode above. If you need more than 26 rows, you'll have to tweak it.